# echo string/parameter into array - php

Tags: php, arrays, insert

Still have problems with inserting key-values to associative array in php from file.

```
<?
function RandomLine($filename) {
    $lines = file($filename);
    echo $lines[array_rand($lines)];
}

$a1 = RandomLine("p1.txt");

$a = array(
    1 => array(
        0 => "value1",
        1 => "value2",
        2 => "value3",
        3 => "value4",
        4 => "value5",
        7 => 4
    ),
    2 => array(
        0 => "value1a",
        1 => "value2a",
        2 => "value3a",
        3 => "value4a",
        4 => "value5a",
        7 => 4
    ),
    3 => array(
        //THE PROBLEM IS HERE, can't echo $a1 variable!
        echo $a1;
    ),
);

?>
```

File p1.txt has two lines:

```
0 => "value1",  1 => "value2",  2 => "value3",  3 => "value 4",  4 => "value5",  7 => 1
0 => "value6",  1 => "value7",  2 => "value8",  3 => "vealue9",  4 => "value10",  7 => 3
```

I get error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting ')'`

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You dont echo a value into an array.

You just use its name like so

```
3 => array(
    1 => $a1,

  ...
  ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove comma after last array:

```
3 => array(
//THE PROBLEM IS HERE, can't echo $a1 variable!
echo $a1;
)
```

Move echo after array deffinition:

```
3 => array(
  //THE PROBLEM IS HERE, can't echo $a1 variable!
  )
);
echo $a1;
```

If you want to echo something from array called $a do it like this:

```
echo $a[0];
```

This will return only first array so if you want "value1" from first array do it like this:

```
echo $a[1][0];
```